# Cursor in the middle of a textarea box?

Tags: html, css

In a very simple HTML form I've created, I've asked the user to provide additional details and have coded this section as:

```
<textarea rows="1" cols="50" wrap="physical" name="comments">

</textarea>
```

Any idea why the cursor starts off at the middle of this box? Well, it's not directly at the middle, but it's definitely not at the start (top left) corner of the box. I see a lot of solutions here and they all require Javascript to correct this. Is there a way to do this with just html?

Comment: Why make a one row textarea? Either use a text field or make the textarea taller. Also, can you post an example of what you're seeing? This alone doesn't exhibit the behavior you're describing.

Comment: @j08691: sorry, that was an example only. In my form, it is taller than just 1 row. However, based on the solution, it looks this is sufficient to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

What happens when you change it to:

```
<textarea rows="1" cols="50" wrap="physical" name="comments"></textarea>
```

I think it's not starting at the beginning because you've got whitespace inside the tag.

Comment: Ah that could be it! depends on whether or not he means "middle" exactly or just "not the left side" (or he has exactly 25 spaces inside of it :) ).

Comment: Concise answers like this to (seemingly) absurd problems that would otherwise waste a valuable time debugging are what make stack overflow a wonderful resource. Thank you!

Comment: I literally just had the ending tag on a new line and it was causing the same issue. You'd think in 2019 this wouldn't happen.

Comment: Yeah, you just have to put both the starting and end tags inline

Answer (score 11):

The reason that this happens is because you have white space in between the `<textarea>` tag. Try this

```
<textarea rows="1" cols="50" wrap="physical" name="comments"></textarea>
```

Comment: This was my issue, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That generally happens when we enter a space between two opening and closing "textarea" tag for readibility.

i.e your opening `<textarea>` tag and Closing `</textarea>` tags are on different lines or there are some white spaces between them.

Answer (score 0):

That does sound strange. Have you looked in firebug to see what CSS effects it? The only thing that comes to mind is that it's under the influence of `text-align: center`